# What is the Problem with these conditional Statement?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I am facing an issue with my script. It is a form with a gender select option. When the page loads the value of `gender` == `true`, therefore  it should satisfy the first part of the `if` condition, and set `gender` to `male`. Why it is going into the else condition and assigning the value `gender = female`?

In the database the `gender` column has a bit datatype.

```
var gender = data[0].Gender; // gender = true 
if (gender == "true") {
    gender = "male";
} else {
    gender = "female"; // gender = female
}
```

Comment: A string is not a boolean

Comment: so how this could be resolved ?

Comment: "true"(string) and true (Boolean) are not same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `if (gender == "true") {` to `if (gender == true) {`. You should be comparing booleans, not strings.

EDIT: As the commenter says, `if (gender) {` would be more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Since "true" is not of type boolean but of type string, the comparison `if (true == "true")` will always fail.

```
var gender = data[0].Gender;      ** gender = true/false **
   if (gender) {
     gender = "male";
   }
   else {
     gender = "female"; **gender= female**
   }
```

Here'r two links regarding [boolean from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp) and [comparisons](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Comment: I don’t think I mentioned how long it took you to answer, just the poor quality of it. Don’t try to pretend it’s rude to be told you’ve posted a poor answer. You didn’t have to post it.

Comment: @Clive No reason to be rude - and thanks for your advice what to post or not your majesty ;) Brighten up a bit and don't be so grumpy - there's no reason to be so mean, Anyways - I wish a you a pleasant day ;)

Comment: Poor answers make me grumpy, you’re just going to have deal with that. Smiley? Sure :)

Comment: @Clive simple question - simple answer.. ;) Elaborate on what makes this poor?

Comment: @iLuvLogix It's code-only answer without explanation why it should be done in this way and you're using invalid comments

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself. Factor in these newly added, frankly tangential and not helpful, links to a resource that most in our biz know is traditionally dodgy (and won't forgive, no matter what w3fools claims now), and that's a perfect storm. To be honest we get thousands of answers a day, I'm not going to continue wasting my time proving the obvious to you - you can take this as advice, slightly grumpy or otherwise, or you can leave it. Bye!

Comment: That was provided in the comments already - but let me edit my answer..